# conda build for several python versions with binary dependencies

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have built an own dll (call it myLib.pyd) using Boost.Python. The dll are linked to correct python lib file, e.g $PYTHONHOME/libs/python39.lib

My directory structure looks like

```
binaries/
         myLib_py39.pyd
         myLib_py310.pyd
conda-recipe/
         build.bat
         conda_build_config.yaml
         meta.yaml
my-package/
           __init__.py
           myLib.pyd
```

Where myLib.pyd is a manual copy of *either* myLib_py39.pyd or myLib_py310.pyd.

meta.yaml looks like

```
package:
  name: my-package
 
source:
  path: ..

requirements:
  build:
    - python {{ python }}
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python
```

and meta.yaml

```
python:
    - 3.9
    - 3.10
```

When I run `conda build "conda-recipe`" it correctly builds packages for both python-3.9 and python-3.10, but somehow I need to make sure that I copy the correct .pyd file from the binary directory into the package before building for each individual python version.

Another alternative is to include both .pyd files into the conda package and make sure I have some python logic to import the correct one, but that seems not like how other packages do it.

I tried to make a powershell script that loops through python-versions, but my solution was too hackish and I think that conda in some way could solve this for me. Note - it works fine and as expected, as long as I manually copy in the correct .pyd version

Answer (score 0):

The Python version should be available to the `bld.bat`/`build.sh` in the environment variable `PY_VER` (see [documentation on environment variables](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-set-during-the-build-process)). You could use that to add logic to copy the correct file.

Note that, at least for Conda Forge recipes, such binary copying is frowned upon. Instead, it is preferred that all binaries are compiled in the build process and use dynamic linking against Conda packages. This helps keep package sizes minimal.